# MS SQL remove everything before a Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to write some code that removes everything After the first number that appears in a sentence.

So if the field is E1W

I want to return just E, same if it is EP4, just return the EP. I have tried various substrings, charindex and patindexs put can not get it right.

Comment: yeah my mistake, apologies. updated questions now

Answer (score 2):

`PATINDEX` helps:

```
SELECT Left(field, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', field + '1') - 1)
```

The `field + '1'` avoids an error if there is no digit in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PATINDEX`:

```
SELECT *,
       LEFT(s,IIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',s)>0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',s)-1,0))
FROM (SELECT 'E1W' AS s 
      UNION SELECT 'EP4' 
      UNION SELECT 'ABC') z;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/YRMS80714)**